# FireFox inset box-shadow bug

Tags: firefox, css

I know there is a bug with box-shadow(inset) in Firefox. It lags a lot.
I'm trying to disable box-shadow for FF 11. But -moz-box-shadow:none!important; is not working! Browser just begins to use the property box-shadow (without -moz).

```
.class {
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #fff; /* for opera */
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #fff; /* for webkit browsers */
    -moz-box-shadow:none!important; /* for FF */
}
```

Need help!

Comment: Prefixed attributes and features are not meant for this purpose. Solution: you could try to check the browser in javascript and add styling accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-moz-box-shadow` is no longer supported by new versions of Firefox.
Hopefully Chrome and Safari will continue to support `-webkit-box-shadow`. So solution may be:

```
.class {
    box-shadow: none; /* turn off shadow for all */
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px; /* turn on shadow for Chrome & Safari */
}
```